# Как сравнить значения массивов и в случае совпадения выполнить запись в проверяемый массив php?

Tags: php

Есть два многомерных массива, `arr1` и `arr2`. Необходимо проверить, есть ли совпадения по значению `arr1[$i][3]` с `arr2[$i][0]`, 
если есть дописать в конец массива `arr1[$i]` значение `arr2[$i][1]`.

```
<?php

$arr1 = array( 
    array('a', 'b', 'c', '2231'),
    array('a' , 'b' , 'c' , '2344')
    );

$arr2 = array(
    array('2231', '658'),
    array('2456' . '0')
    );

$size_arr2 = count($arr2);


$size = count($arr1);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $size; $i++) {

    $arr1[$i][] = 'some';

} 


print_r($arr1);
```

// Первый массив в который дописывмем значение из второго массива если есть совпадение по [$i][3]

array (

```
[0] => Array 
(
    [0] => google / cpc 
    [1] => Paris city
    [2] => Oneclick_Order_0983451
    [3] => 456894 // значение для сравения 
    [4] => 0 
)

[1] => Array
(
    [0] => google / cpc 
    [1] => Kyiv city
    [2] => Oneclick_Order_0983421
    [3] => 456891  // значение для сравения 
    [4] => 0 
)

[2] => Array
(
    [0] => google / cpc 
    [1] => Kyiv city
    [2] => Oneclick_Order_0483421 
    [3] => 456892 // значение для сравения 
    [4] => 0 
)
```

);

// Второй массив со стоимостью

array (

```
[0] => Array 
(
    [0] => 456894 // значение для сравения 
    [1] => 152.45 // значение которое записываем 
)

[1] => Array
(
    [0] => 657585 
    [1] => 0
)

[2] => Array
(
    [0] => 655685 
    [1] => 845.69
)
```

)

На выходе получаем первый массив с заполеными ключами из второго.

Comment: а надо то первый с первым сравнивать элементы? или каждый с каждым?

Comment: каждый с каждым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если требуется сранивнить каждый с каждым, а не только `i`-тые, то как вариант:

```
$tmp = array_column($arr2, 1, 0);
foreach($arr1 as &$v){
     if(array_key_exists($v[3], $tmp)){
         $v[] = $tmp[$v[3]];
     }
}
```

в целом цикл можно заменить на `array_walk`, но смысла нет, короче не станет

Comment: оно! Спасибо огромное )

Answer (score 0):

вы берете первый элемент из $arr1 и сравниваете с первым из $arr2. Потом второй из arr1, и второй arr2. А надо взять первый элемент первого, и проверит на совпадение все элементы второго. То есть у вас arr1[i] и arr2[i], а надо arr2[j]. Фактически в вопросе зря использованы одинаковые индексы $i

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr1); $i++) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $k => $v) {
        if ($arr1[$i][3] == $v[0]) {
            $arr1[$i][] = $v[1];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но работает только для первого массива, а у меня их 90 и больше.

Comment: Тогда полностью сформулируйте задачу

Comment: Получаю данные из google analytics ( два массива с конверсией , товарами , ид объявления  и второй с ид и стоимостью ). Нужно сформировать 1 массив и записать его в файл для передачи в 1С. Попробовал вот так но чет не то...     for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($orders); $i++) {
      for ($l = 0; $l <= sizeof($rows); $l++) {
        if ($orders[$i][4] == $rows[$l][0]) {
            $orders[$i][] = $rows[$l][1];
          }
        else {
          $orders[$i][] = 'not have cost';
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Сравнить ид объявлений в двух массивах и если есть совпадение записать затраченную стоимость

Comment: Все равно не понятно. В задаче сравнивается 3й элемент, в комментарии 4й. Надо брать последний элемент в массиве и его сравнивать? Это `$arr[sizeof($arr)-1]` - берите его и вставляйте в `if`

Comment: обновил вопрос , надеюсь так будет понятнее. спасибо.

Comment: После обновления мне все равно не понятно чем мой код плох. Сравнивает как надо, подставляет как надо. Что не так?

Comment: @IvanBolnikh вы берете первый элемент из `$arr1` и сравниваете с первым из `$arr2`. Потом второй из `arr1`, и второй `arr2`. А надо взять первый элемент первого, и проверит на совпадение все элементы второго. То есть  у вас `arr1[i]` и `arr2[i]`, а надо `arr2[j]`. Фактически в вопросе зря использованы одинаковые индексы `$i`